# instance() method in java constructor declaration

Tags: java, spring

Need help in understanding this piece of code, what is this `instance()` after construction.

```
@Component
public class ServiceHelper
{

   private static ServiceHelper instance;

   public static ServiceHelper instance()
   {
     if (instance == null)
     {
        instance = new ServiceHelper();
        instance.init();
     }

     return instance;
   }

  protected void init()
 { 
     ....
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  `public static ServiceHelper instance()` is a class method, and because it's static, this way you not need an instance of this class to access this method necessarily.

Note that `instance()` is the method signature and it has nothing to do with class variable named `private static ServiceHelper instance;`, they just have the same name.